# Count substring occurrence

Tags: c#

I have a text file called info.txt with string in it.

info.txt

```
05331
02555
03211
05222
04321
02387
03444
03127
05117
03680
03881
01579
03111
```

My output should be in new.txt

Output new.txt

```
05331
02555
03211
1
05222
04321
02387
03444
03127
2
05117
03680
03881
01579
03111
3
```

Basically I should get the count of all strings starting with "03" and print the count before the substring "01"

```
       try
       {
           String line;
           Int counter =0;
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Files\\gamenam.txt");
           StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Files\\gamenam_1.txt");

           while ((line = sr.ReadLine())!= null)
           {
               if (line.substring(0,2) == "05")
               {
                   sw.Write(counter.ToString());
                   counter =0;
               }
               If (line.subString(0,2) =="03")
               {
                   //loop
                   counter++;
               }

               sw.WriteLine(line);
           }

           sr.Close();
           sw.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
       }
       finally
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Exception finally block.");
       }
   }
```

After writing my code I could only get.

```
0
05331
02555
03211
1
05222
04321
02387
03444
03127
2
05117
03680
03881
01579
03111
```

The 0 on the first line shouldn't be the since I have no stings before and there is no count for last count.

Please help guys.

Comment: Have read your samples twice and still can't get logic of numbers you trying to get. You say you want to print count before substring `01` but in expected output you print it before `05`

Comment: As the first line of the file begins 05 it immediately writes out the counter. Basically, you need to read AHEAD, rather than BEHIND, that is, you need to know what the NEXT line is before deciding to write out the counter.

Comment: According to the output you provided it looks like the logic is that you print the count each time the string starting with "05" appears AND at the end of the file. Is this correct?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy sorry for that, I meant 05

Comment: @user3251829 is it possible that `05` line will be last in input file? Also should you write count each time `05` is found, or only if there was `03` between them?

Comment: The first two characters of each record, is the record identifier. Every new client inside the file starts with "01".Count the number of records that starts with "03" for each client. At the end of each client (before the next "05" record), print the count of the "03"

Comment: @user3251829 please answer my previous questions. And explain why yo don't print count before 01579 which is start of new client?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy if my code finds a 05 it should write the count of 03. But my problem is that the last record is 03, meaning my count doesn't write the count since there is no 05. But I want it to write the count of 03 even if my file reaches a point where it can't find substring 05.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I keep making a mistake with that, the new client is actually 05, meaning it should only write count before 05

Comment: @ChrisHammond I get what your saying, I got the program to write the last count value for 03 since there are no more 05, but now I just don't know how I'm going to read ahead rather then behind. The other code I wrote completely removed the 05 on the first line, but the 03 is very important as its client identifiers. All I need is a way to print show the 03 as the first line but not show any count, maybe by starting to count from second line

Comment: @user3251829 How big is the file? Is it possible to read the entire file into a `string[]` and then process in memory using a `for...next` loop

Comment: @user3251829 I've posted an answer with slightly modified version of your code using READ AHAED

Comment: @ChrisHammond thanks for your input, but I'm still getting the same result, my count is working perfectly, the thing I'm missing is to rather ignore the first line or something so that when my code starts running, it does necessarily print the count compared to first line, because my first line is starts with a identifier used to write count wen reaching it

Comment: @user3251829 I am sorry, I don't understand. My code below gave the output expected that you wrote above... So, am I missing something. 

Your code (and expected output) indicates that you need counter before an "05" line but then you say you need it before the "01"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your `while loop` you can try something like that:

```
...
Boolean isFirstLine = true;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
  // If line starts with "05" we should print out counter 
  // (that is number of "03" started lines)
  // unless it is the first line in the file
  if (line.StartsWith("05")) {
    if (!isFirstLine)
      sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString()); 

    sw.WriteLine(line); 
    counter = 0;  
    isFirstLine = false; 

    continue;
  }

  sw.WriteLine(line);

  if (line.StartsWith("03")) 
    counter += 1;

  // We should also print out counter after the last file line
  // if, say, counter > 0 
  if (sr.Peek() < 0) // <- No next line
    if (counter > 0)
      sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString());

  isFirstLine = false;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's code for using a READ AHEAD implementation. Just before the end of the loop, you read the next line, if it is null (end of file) or it starts with "05" then you output and reset counter

```
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;
                //Pass the file path and name to the StreamReader constructer
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("gamenam.txt");
                //Pass the file path and name to the StreamReader constructer
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("gamenam_1.txt");


                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "03")
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }

                    sw.WriteLine(line);

                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if ((line == null) || (line.StartsWith("05")))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }

                //Close
                sr.Close();
                sw.Close();
            }
            //Catching exception
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Exception Message
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception finally block.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you r help guys, from all you input, I finally got the output I needed.

I wrote my code like this

```
       String line;
       int counter = 0;
       Boolean isFirstLine = true;
       try
       {
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Files\\gamenam.txt");
           StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Files\\gamenam_1.txt");

           while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "01")
               {
                   if (!isFirstLine)
                   {
                       sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
                       counter = 0;  
                   }
               }
               if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "05")
               {
                   counter++;
               }
               sw.WriteLine(line);
               if (sr.Peek() < 0)
               {
                   sw.Write(counter.ToString());
               }
               isFirstLine = false;
           }
           sr.Close();
           sw.Close();
       }
```